# How to get Error Alert for hybrid iphone application by New Relic

Tags: newrelic, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using New Relic tool for hybrid mobile application and it is showing alert for session and Response time but not showing any error alert. Even i am getting rest error 404 in my sencha mobile app.Is there any specific setting for error alert which i am missing .

Regards,

Bharti sharma

Answer (score 0):

New Relic does not directly alert on specific errors. You could set up an alert to trigger on your error rate or on Apdex dropping below a specific threshold. Errors will negatively affect your apdex so if you have multiple errors this may give you the notification you are looking for.

Information on setting up alert policies can be found [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alert-policies/alert-policies-dashboard).

More information about Apdex can be found on the New Relic knowledge base, [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/site/apdex-measuring-user-satisfaction), and [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/site/changing-your-apdex-settings).